# What does “Fabs days hair” means?

Tags: meaning

What does “Fabs days hair” means in the following content?

> A bouncy funk single recorded entirely alone by Paul for McCartney II, the promo clip for Coming Up featured him (and Linda) cloned as the members of a band, The Plastic Macs, whose bassist was “Beatle Paul”, sporting collarless jacket and reviving his Fabs days hair tosses

Comment: The Beatles were once affectionately known by the nickname The Fab Four. I suspect there are some typos in that sentence and it should read "...and reviving his Fab days hair-tosses" - To mean he reprises the hair-tosses he used to do when he was in the Beatles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Beatles are known the "Fab-Four" short for the Fabulous Four. This was because of their combined music talent and daunting good looks.

In their early all the band members wore similar bowl style haircuts. The line would mean he had styled his hair in that fashion.

[image]